# Testing already Open Browser with Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I do not want to open a new browser by @browser = Watir::Browser.new (:ie) but i want to work with manually opened browser using Watir-Webdriver. 
How would I do that ?

I thought it may be something like this 
 browser(:title => "Browser Title").text_field( :id => 'Field Id').set 'abc'

it seems like I need to create an Object of browser class to work it .. 
Please guide me?

Answer (score 4):

Selenium-webdriver does not have functionality for attaching to existing browsers. This feature was requested, but closed as not feasible (see [Issue 18](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18#c48)).

If you are only using IE, you could consider using Watir-Classic, which has functionality for attaching to existing browsers:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title,  "Browser Title")
browser.text_field( :id => 'Field Id').set 'abc'
```

The main part of the API is the same between Watir-Webdriver and Watir-Classic. There are some small differences depending on what you are doing. Note that if your code is doing `require 'watir'`, you might already be using Watir-Classic.

Comment: Thanks Justin! That is working as you suggested :)